# How can i extract the year and month from multiple date columns in a dataframe at once? (getting an error)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df with four datetime columns. Some of these columns have null values in. I would like to extract the year and month from each column. For an individual column I have done this:

`df['year-month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`

However when I try to apply this to all four columns at once using:

`df["m" + pd.Index(cols)] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`

I get the following error:
`ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add some example data, for instance by doing df[cols].head(10) and pasting the data in your question

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to execute a function along an axis of the DataFrame.

Original **df**

```py
           0          1          2          3          4
0 2021-01-31 2021-02-28 2021-03-31        NaT 2021-05-31
1 2022-02-28        NaT 2022-04-30 2022-05-31 2022-06-30
2 2023-03-31 2023-04-30 2023-05-31 2023-06-30 2023-07-31
3 2024-04-30 2024-05-31 2024-06-30        NaT 2024-08-31
```

```py
new_col_names = [f"m{c}" for c in df.columns]
df[new_col_names] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
print(df)
```

Output

```py
           0          1          2          3          4       m0       m1       m2       m3       m4
0 2021-01-31 2021-02-28 2021-03-31        NaT 2021-05-31  2021-01  2021-02  2021-03      NaN  2021-05
1 2022-02-28        NaT 2022-04-30 2022-05-31 2022-06-30  2022-02      NaN  2022-04  2022-05  2022-06
2 2023-03-31 2023-04-30 2023-05-31 2023-06-30 2023-07-31  2023-03  2023-04  2023-05  2023-06  2023-07
3 2024-04-30 2024-05-31 2024-06-30        NaT 2024-08-31  2024-04  2024-05  2024-06      NaN  2024-08
```